# Google API: Remove all data from the list at once

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I have a customer match list id that I want to remove all data from it at once (without deleting it)
i'm using the Python client library, it has examples, however for this specific case:

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/remarketing/audience-types/customer-match#remove_all_data_from_the_list_at_once

I'm not understanding how to write a python code to achieve it, I appreciate the help!